# Bitmap decoding taking time (Out of Memory)

Tags: android

When I create a Bitmap it needed to decoding the file `[BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream, null, bitmapfactoryOption)]`
but it take lot of time in case of bulky images.

I want to set this bitmap in `ImageView` for display Thumbnails. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The system will create thumbnails for you. You can use the media provider to retrieve these.

Info on content providers:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

A list of some content providers which Android exposes to you:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/package-summary.html

The media store provder:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html

Comment: Thank you, but in this case without decoding of image Application become cresh (out of memory error) Because of big size of image, and when i decode it then it take a lot of time. so is there any other way to display big size image in imageView (for thumbnails) quickly.    Plz help .